# Anchor Point Adjustment

Tags: phaser-framework

I am working on trying to change the anchor point of a sprite.

Most of the examples I have seen look something like this:

```
this.asset.anchor.setTo(0.5, 0.5);
```

But I am not really clear on how the this keyword is used in javascript.

How do I adjust the anchor point of a sprite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For more information about the "this" keyword in JavaScript, I encourage you to have a look at the questions that deal about this specific problem, such as this one : [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

However, from the Phaser point of view, the anchor point is the anchor of Phaser Sprite or a Phaser Image, so to change the anchor point of any sprite, change it after the sprite has been created :

`var sprite = game.add.sprite(10,10,'');
// and then 
sprite.anchor.set(0.5);`

Also your example was not super clear, "this.assets" isn't super explicit in my opinion as a sprite doesn't necessarily come from an asset, which example were you looking at ?

Comment: Oh gosh... It was long enough ago now that I don't remember which example it was. Sorry...